# MySQL удаление базы данных

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Забыл пароль от mysql, пробовал ресетнуть его, ничего не получалось, говорило нет доступа. Думал быстрее будет удалить и наново поставить.. удалилось по ходу криво.. выбивает ошибке при установке. Как все полностью удалить правильно? ubuntu 16.04
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переустанови убунту

Comment: не шутите так))

Comment: Как же вы затрахали скринами терминала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Чтобы полностью удалить MySQL из вашей системы, выполните следующую команду в терминале:**

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**Если после этого у вас не удалились пакеты, попробуйте удалить их например вот так:**

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql* -V
sudo rm -rv /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rv /var/log/mysql*
sudo rm -rv /etc/mysql*
```

**Можно удалить и таким способом :**

```
find / -iname ‘mysql*’ -exec sudo rm -rf {} \;
```

**Установить MySQL:**

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Удачи !

Comment: dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёты apport не записаны, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                           Обрабатываются триггеры для libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (229-4ubuntu16) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-19) …
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @xxx44552 MySQL удаляется тем способом каким я указал.Если не удаляeтся то надо сидеть перед вашим ПК и поочередно пытаться исправлять ошибки :)

Comment: Эта ошибка уже при повторной установке, поле удаления вашим способом

Comment: @xxx44552 `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` Устанавливайте этим способом

Comment: после удаления вашим способом и установке выбивает под конец такую ошибку, что скинул выше

Comment: @xxx44552  Я обновил ответ. Скорее всего удалив ` /var/lib/mysql` должно заработать.

Comment: не помогло, все ту же ошибку выбивает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58405/discussion-between-vanya-avchyan-and-xxx44552).

Answer (score 1):

причина проблемы - баг установки
вот решение нашел :)

Открыть файл /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst и закомментировать строку 95

```
### /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks install mysql "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf"
```

[На сайте askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643667/does-someone-knows-how-to-fix-this-installation-bug-in-ubuntumysql-server-5-6-e)